# jquery .each() combing all values on each run through

Tags: jquery, grouping, each

My objective is to group elements on the page based on a dataset of their location. The content is already being rendered onto the page, and I want a Location header for each unique location above the events being held there. The structure of the page would be Class Name > Location > class times

I'm doing a few .each() loops to try to find what I need, but the values of what I think should be separate runs of the first each loop are all being combined together. The thing is, the each loop is still running multiple times.

```
$('.class-Info').each(function () 
{
    var className = $("h2").text();
    var eventLocations = [];
    $('.scheduledClass').each(function (index) 
    {
        eventLocations[index] = $(this).data("location");
    }); 

    var key = "";
    var uniqueLocations = [];
    $(eventLocations).each(function (index, location)
    {
        if (key !== eventLocations[index])
        {
            key = eventLocations[index];
            uniqueLocations.push(eventLocations[index]);
        }
     });

     console.log ("For " + className + " the locations are " + uniqueLocations);

});
```

Here is my code. I hope my question makes sense. Take a look at the console to see the results I'm getting.

http://jsfiddle.net/qnpr9fbh/5/

Comment: Just made a small edit, I realized that it was not getting the correct `className` during each loop over the `.scheduledClass` elements. Had to add the same `$(this).find('h2')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you want to get here.

http://jsfiddle.net/qnpr9fbh/7/

If you update your first each loop like so (adding the `$(this).find`) It will look for `.scheduledClass` elements that exist within the current `.class-Info`. Before, it was just looking for *all of them*. This results in different, seemingly appropriate, console output.

```
$(this).find('.scheduledClass').each(function (index) {
    eventLocations[index] = $(this).data("location");
});

// Edit: Also make sure you select the correct "h2" by adding the $(this).find()
var className = $(this).find("h2").text();
```

> Console Output:
>
> For DocuSign Administrator Account Logistics TrainingCreating Docusign
>   Digital Workflows: Templates the locations are Location TBD
>
> For Creating Docusign Digital Workflows: Templates the locations are
>   Test1,Willis Tower,Location TBD

Is that along the lines of what you were looking for?

---

jQuery has some handy function that can make your code quite a bit smaller and cleaner, too:

```
$('.class-Info').each(function () {
    var className = $(this).find("h2").text(),
        eventLocations = $.map($(this).find('.scheduledClass'), function (elem) {
            return $(elem).data("location");
        }),
        uniqueLocations = $.unique(eventLocations.slice());

     console.log ("For " + className + " the locations are " + uniqueLocations);
});
```

- **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** - Will loop over selected elements and build an array out of the items returned from the function.
- [**.unique()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/) - Will reduce an array or list of jQuery elements and reduce it down to an array of only the unique values.
- **[Javascript Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)** - I'm calling this on the eventLocations array because `.slice()` will clone the array. Necessary because `.unique()` will modify the array that it receives. So just give it a copy, and the original is not modified.

Comment: Thank you for the extra functions! I've never seen map or unique before, and I recognize slice though have forgot about it.

Comment: To clarify about the solution to my version of code. Just because an iteration of each() is looking at one element doesn't mean the next jquery selector would only look inside of that block? Defining $(this) is the part that restricts jquery to the code inside that first element?

Comment: Yeah that's right. When you do a selector like `$('.class')` it will look inside of ALL of the HTML for `.class` elements, but you can restrict the search to children element of something by selecting the parent first and then calling `.find()` as I did.

Comment: Understanding what `this` means in Javascript is a big part of learning what the code is doing -- jQuery code especially. Inside of a jQuery `.each()` loop, `this` is the element that is being iterated over. That element is also passed into the each function. Inside of an each function, the element is the second parameter. Inside of the map function, it's the first. I could have used `this` instead of `elem` inside of that map function and the code would have behaved the same.

Comment: example: http://jsfiddle.net/14hpvhdn/ - This article does a decent job of explaining it further (https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified). If you google anything like "understanding jQuery this" you should find tons of articles explaining it further with good examples

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share all of this information. It's been very helpful. If I had the reputation, I would be upvoting.

Comment: No problem. You'll get plenty of rep asking more questions. jQuery questions usually get answered in just a few minutes.